# Batch script compiler

Tags: batch-file

Is there any batch script compiler available? I have a very big batch file and I want to check where my syntax is going wrong. Also using @pause and echo I can check what's going wrong but a compiler would be a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the best you could find is a syntax checker, not a real compiler, as in batch many constructs could only *compile* at runtime.
Nearly each `%var%` expansion needs to *compile* in the moment of expansion, as the content could change everything.
Also the possibility of self modifying code makes this problem a bit tricky.

Perhaps someone, sometimes will write a batch debugger, that should be possible.

Comment: You haven't already? ;-) (Actually, I'd be content with an open-source reference implementation too :P)

Comment: It's on my todo list, if I find the time, I will implement one with javascript

Comment: Hm, Javascript might be a less ideal choice, given that batch files frequently resort to native programs as well (unless you want it not to run in the browser).

Comment: I want to run it in a browser sandbox, for better visualisation, and external files should also be _virtual_. So the user can copy&paste the batch file into the browser and see how each line will be expanded, the variable and function stack with the cached command blocks